# Headless testing in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, headless

I opted to just ask my question directly here, I'm quite confused with all the details I've gathered regarding headless testing in robot framework.

Is there a documentation that has all the instruction on how to implement headless testing in Robot Framework from scratch? Like what are the needed pre-requisites?like xvfb?or anything else?Hope you can help me. Thanks

By the way, I'm currently using Robot Framework with pycharm as ide in(Windows OS). Thank You

Comment: Welcome at [so]. It is expected that questions meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part. This is typically done by showing us the code that you're working on and providing us with some details on the expected and observed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I just use headless Chrome:

```
${chromeOptions}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${downloadDir}
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --lang\=${browserLocale}
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --window-size\=1366,768
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
Create Webdriver    ${browserName}    chrome_options=${chromeOptions}
```

Comment: Hi @Lubos, if you're referring to the headless chrome you mean you've installed the chrome canary? or the usual chrome? I've tried your code and was prompted with this error, TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error.

Comment: @lee This is a part of the usual Chrome release. Btw. if you don't need some of the extended features of this (for example I think that file downloads basically do not work in the basic mode) you can just use following:
http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser

    Open Browser    ${url}    headlesschrome

Comment: I've already tried the Open Browser ${url} headlesschrome but it seems that its not treated as a browser?i've updated my selenium2library already though. I'm prompted with the ff error. ValueError: Headless Chrome is not a supported browser. I wonder if there is a pre-requisite action in order to use the headlesschrome?

Comment: @lee Try using SeleniumLibrary instead of the Selenium2Library

Comment: it seems to work, but after the execution of open browser it no longer detect the element present on the landed url?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't think I got this :)

Comment: Open Browser ${url}  headlesschrome     input text ${elementId}   value                                                                                  an error arises stating that the elementId is not found in the page

Comment: Interesting - I'm not aware of any of this as I use what I posted above. Maybe try debugging that a bit and let's see if that works for you or not.

Comment: Hope your getting me @Lubos  btw. Thank you for all the responses 

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem using the new Browser option in Open Browser (SeleniumLibrary)
          `Open Browser   {url}     headlessfirefox`
But i'm having an error when i run it using the headlesschrome, indicating that "gpu_process_transport.cc(1017) Lost UI shared context" "Devtools listening on ...etc'

What could be the problem here?

Comment: so you end up using firefox in headless mode? Does it still not work for headless chrome?

Answer (score -3):

Use phantomjs for this. Download phantomjs driver and set path variable or you can use below code:
${EXECDIR} is the path where driver exists

```
Set Environment Variable  webdriver.phantomjs.driver  ${EXECDIR}/phantomjs.exe
Open Browser    https://google.com    phantomjs
Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: phantomjs is not being maintained anymore. It's a dead product. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344